# remember a variable's history

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a page that slides right and left and loads new content using ajax. A variable gets set to leftslide or rightslide depending on the slide direction.

When you click the back button in the browser the html5 popstate event enables and loads the last page using ajax. Now using the variable I can determin what direction to slide in when the back button is pushed `if (var  direction == 'leftslide'){ direction = 'rightslide'}` (to get a nice "back" effect).

But if you push the backbutton twice the slide will not always be correct sine it will just reverse the slide instead of looking at the slide of that paticular page.

So is there any way to save a variables history and get the order back using javascript?

thanks for reading and thinking about this :)

Comment: I didn't give the -1, but I did find your question confusing; perhaps somebody else found it so confusing that they downvoted.

Comment: alright :). Well I don't know how to asj this diferently so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var history = [];
var position = 1;

function onSlide() {
    history.push(currentPage);
};

function lastPage() {
    return history.length && history[history.length - 2];
};

function currentPage() {
    return history.length && history[history.length - 1];
};

function goBack() {
    if (history.length) {
        position += 1;

        navigateTo(history[history.length - position]);
    }
}

function goForward() {
    if (history.length) {
        position -= 1;

        navigateTo(history[history.length - position]);
    }
}
```

Get the idea?

Basically, we are saving each page we visit in an array. When we navigate through history, we keep track of our position in history by updating an integer variable that indicates which slot in the history array to check.

Comment: how can I save a variable with that? isn't that just for URL's?

Comment: You can push anything you want into the history array - variables, functions, numbers...

Comment: and when I move back twice how can the function know it should use -3 and not -2? while still being able to navigate normally :s. Sorry for asking 234 questions :p

Comment: No, that's a very valid question. I will edit the code to show how.

Comment: last question :p. is this correct: var direction = left; history.push(direction);?

It doesn't seem to work for me but it might be something else :)

Comment: left would have to be defined somewhere as a variable. Maybe you meant to say direction = "left";

Answer (score 0):

This might help: [ajax history libraries](http://codinginparadise.org/weblog/2005/09/ajax-history-libraries.html). Never used ajax or javascript before

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me more like you want to save some state in a cookie which you can then read anytime the page is loaded.  You can make a cookie scoped to the entire site, a branch of the site or just a path.